# AWS CodeCommit someone has given me a User, an Access key ID and a Secret Access Key. How do I use these to clone their remote repository locally?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I'm a remote frontend developer working as a freelancer on a project for someone else. I'm used to using git for version control and usually I use a service like GitBucket, GitLab or GitHub, but for the first time I've been asked to use AWS CodeCommit.

The code team I'm working with have provided me with a 'user', an 'Access key ID' and a 'Secret Access Key'. I usually use https, but I think this means I have to use SSH.

I've tried to read the AWS documents but they are so horrifically overly complicated and I'm having real trouble following what I need to do to simply clone the remote repository to my machine and then be able to pull/push my changes.

Can anyone give me a simple step by step instruction on what I need to do to use git to connect and clone this remote repository using the details I've been give?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggesting you to please go through this [AWS documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-connect.html) for connecting to AWS codecommit repository and clone it. I addition [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html) is also helpful to connect using SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use it using https but it's a bit of a hassle on the first time setting it up.
You need to install the aws CLI and configure it with those credentials. Then you need to install the git-remote-codecommit tool (not required per se but makes things much easier).

A whole guide can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-git-remote-codecommit.html#setting-up-git-remote-codecommit-prereq).
Summary is:

- set up an IAM user and access keys (you already have that)
- install the aws CLI
- run `aws configure` and use the provided keys (select the correct default region!)
- install the codecommit Helper tool using `pip install git-remote-codecommit`
- clone the repo using the tool `git clone codecommit://<repo name here>` or when using named profiles `git clone codecommit://<profile here>@<repo name here>`

There are some things that can be misconfigured (region, profile name) so if it doesn't work out the first time feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: thank you. I'm nearly there with this, but then I hit some errors when I try to connect. I get "Permission denied (publickey) fata: Could not read from remote repository". Do I also need to be setting up keys from my PC? As in generate the codecommit_rsa and codecommit_rsa.pub files? I think the person on the other end providing me the AWS repo and details might not quite understand the process themselves. They seem have set up an IAM user for me, but now they seem to want me to generate these keys files for my user, but obviously I can't because the IAM user is in their AWS account.

Comment: Ah yeah that's weird indeed. You don't need public and private keys. Just the https link

Comment: I can see what is happening here now @LRutten. At first they provided me with an https: version so I was using ```git clone https://their-repo-url``` when I did this it threw up an authentication step and required me to enter a userrname and password. When I wrote back to them and asked for this username and password they then issued me with an SSH version instead so using ```git clone ssh://their-repo-url``` so does this mean that I do have to set up ssh keys from my PC? It's very confusing to me because like I said the IAM user details they gave me they set up in their AWS account.Any ideas?

Comment: Have you followed the guide in my answer? On what step are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you @LRutten Actually I see I was using the wrong git command, they told me to use a standard https: or ssh: connection, but now I see in your instructions you tell me to use codecommit:// now that I've tried this I get this error "The following AWS Region is not available for use with AWS CodeCommit: Europe (Stockholm) eu-north-1. For more information about CodeCommit's availability in AWS Regions, see the AWS CodeCommit User Guide. If an AWS Region is listed as supported but you receive this error, try updating your version of the AWS CLI or the AWS SDKs."

Comment: What region did you configure for your credentials (step 3 in the answer)? In what region is the codecommit repository?

Comment: I did use Europe (Stockholm) eu-north-1 @LRutten, which is the correct location that I was supplied with by the repo owner.

Comment: I'm able to clone from eu-north-1 with no problems. Did you actually update your AWS CLI? Mine is version `aws-cli/2.1.36`